Wix 5.0 Custom Action Condition on Component
I want to apply condition on component on Wxs file and condition value returns from customaction

Create C# customaction to return INSTALL_CONDITION =13 OR 0 Based on condition
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action ="GetInstallPropertyValue" 
      Before="InstallFiles"  >
    </Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>


  <Feature Id="optionalfeature"  Level="1"  >
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponent1">
    </ComponentGroupRef>
  </Feature>
  <Feature Id="mainfeature"  Level="1"    >
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponent2" />
  </Feature>    
  <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponent1" 
   Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"  >
   <Component Id="MainAppl"    Guid="guid"   
     Condition="INSTALL_CONDITION=13"   >
        <File Id="test123.txt" Source="files\test123.txt"   />
    </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponent2" 
        Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"  >
      <Component Id="MainApp2"   Guid="guid" >
        <File Id="test1234.txt" Source="files\test1234.txt" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>

I can see INSTALL_CONDITION populated correctly before InstallFiles action but condition on component is not working and not copying files
If I tried to apply condition on InstallFilesaction inside InstallExecuteSequece its working fine and skipped the InstallFiles action but I need skipped only those components where condition apply
<InstallExecuteSequence
Condition="INSTALL_CONDITION=13">//skipped all files but i need to copy component where condition not present
I also tried to use InstallUISequece but its also not working correctly



Property value should be double-quoted: Condition='INSTALL_CONDITION="13"'. Note outer single-quotes to be able to use unescaped double-quotes.
